# Add text string to existing mySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-like

I would like to be able to mass add a certain text string to a DB table's row.

Example table look like this:

description d
-id
-name
-tag

If d.name has LIKE %text% add 'Tag text' to d.tag.

But d.tag will have data (text) and I would like to add the new text to it.

Comment: It would be useful to supply the SQL query you used to create the table, add data to it, or any attempts you've made. Your table definition is a little confusing. Have you looked up documentation for MySQL `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to append text to `d.tag` like this:

```
UPDATE description d
SET d.tag = CONCAT(d.tag, 'Tag text')
WHERE d.name LIKE '%text%';
```

EDIT: Solution for the first comment (but please see my comment on why this is a bad way to solve the problem):

```
UPDATE description d
SET d.tag = CONCAT(d.tag, 'Tag text')
WHERE d.name LIKE '%text%' and d.tag = '';
UPDATE description d
SET d.tag = CONCAT(d.tag, ', Tag text')
WHERE d.name LIKE '%text%' and d.tag != '';
```

Comment: This work fine! But, let's say I want to have multiple values separated by comma (,) in d.tag I have tried to add ...CONCAT(d.tag,",","Tag text")... If d.tag is empty the data will then be ",Tag text". Can the comma(,) be skipped somehow it d.tag is empty?

Comment: First off, let me say that this is not a good way to solve your problem. You should [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database (see the example and read up on [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)). In your case, you should add a table `tags` with the columns `description_id` and `tagText`. I've edited my answer to address your question, but again, the proper way to solve this is to normalize your table.